# How can I compress a table after having removed a value from it?

Tags: lua, compression, lua-table

I have a table which contains 4 values.

For example:

```
2
4
1
3
```

I use a function to step through the table looking for, lets say the number 1 by using pairs and to get the position of it in the table.

I then use table.remove to remove 1 from that position. What I would like to do now is to compress the table so that it is 3 values long
2
4
3

I'm fairly new to LUA so be gentle with me. :)

What I have is pretty much this:

```
CloseRandomConsole = math.random(1,(#ConsoleTable)) 

If CloseRandomConsole == 1 then 
 for key, value in pairs(ConsoleTable) do 
 if value == "1" then 
  table.remove(ConsoleTable, key) 
 break 
 end 
end
```

I see where I'm going wrong but I hae no idea how to solve it.

```
math.random(1,(#ConsoleTable))
```

I only want to be able to random between one of the values in the table. And when I have randomed that vlue I want it removed so that I will be left with three other values to random from.

Am I confusing you? :)

Comment: If the question isn't a question any more, please choose one answer. Otherwise it will keep appearing on "Unanswered questions"

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean?

```
s = {2,4,1,3} -- the table
for k,v in pairs(s) do 
  if v==1 then 
     table.remove(s,k)
  end
end

print(#s) -- is now 3
for k,v in pairs(s) do print(v) end -- just the 3 values ...
```

@Vitae: When you're asking about anything, you should describe what you want to do, not how you want to do it -- especially when you have no idea what you're doing ...

Maybe you want to remove a random value from the table? Then fetch the value at a random index ...

```
function poprandom( t )
  local idx = math.random(1,#t)
  local ret = t[idx]
  table.remove(t, idx)
  return ret
end
```

Comment: Im using math.random to get a random value from the table. I might be doing it wrong tho.

Comment: CloseRandomConsole = math.random(1,(#ConsoleTable)